# Relate multiple physical network ports to ESXi's virtual network adapter

Tags: networking, vmware-esxi

I have a ESXi 5.0 machine with 1 built-in (in motherboard) network port, plus 2 ethernet PCI cards - each has 4 ports.
To sum up - I have a total of 9 physical network ports in the machine.

How do I correctly relate the physical network port to the ESXi's network label?
If it matters, the virtual machines are mostly linux-based.

Here's an image of how a virtual machine's configs look using VMWare VSphere client 5.0:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no 1:1 relationship between vNICs and pNICs. The vNIC is connected to a port group on a virtual switch which uses physical NICs as uplinks. (Generally, but it doesn't have to. But then your VMs don't have acces to the physical network.) Maybe this picture helps:

[image]

You'll have to look at your (distributed) vSwitch to know what physical NICs are used as uplinks for the port groups your VM is connected to.

Btw: You should consider another naming convention for your port groups. "VM Network *n*" is not really helpful. We generally use IP networks (e.g. 10.20.30.0) but I've also seen names like "App net" and "DB net".

Maybe the [documentation](http://pubs.vmware.com/vsphere-50/topic/com.vmware.vsphere.networking.doc_50/GUID-35B40B0B-0C13-43B2-BC85-18C9C91BE2D4.html) can help you, too.

Answer (score 0):

From the screenshot, I'm trying to guess :

I noticed 7 virtual machine port groups in the "Networking" tab, that was created under this sub link of "Configuration" tab in your selected host.
You have to specify which configuration you created.

An example, if you created `VM Network` in the `Standard Switch: vSwitch0` with only the `Physical Adaptater vmnic0`, `VM Network 1` in a new `Standard Switch: vSwitch1` with `vmnic1`, and so on : it's a hard way to create a 1:1 relationship between vNICs and pNICs.

You have to fully understand how network basis virtualization works.

Also, may I help you :
I saw in your screenshot, you're using, maybe for example, an adapter type `E1000`.

May I suggest to you, for optimization, using the `vmxnet3` after installing the `VMware tools` or `Open-VM-Tools` (easy way with linux from package manager).

Here more information about Choosing a network adapter for your virtual machine :
[Choose network adapter](http://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=1001805)

In some workloads, you may prefer the direct I/O, pass-trough technology provides by compatible Intel CPU like the `VT-d Intel` solution (check Ark Intel and Motherboard requirements).

This allow you to remove the physical adapter from the host, vSwitchs and connect it directly to the virtual machine in the `edit settings` pop up of a virtual machine.
Find the way to proceed with configure Pass-trough in `Advanced Settings` sub link of `Configuration` tab in your selected host.

Hybride solution who clearly improves performance (this is the true way to 1:1), but disable some basics functions provides by a virtualization solution like Snapshots, Clone, vMotion, ... use it carefully.